# Autolayout in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

Good afternoon community,

Any way to autolayout in swiftui so that my view looks good both in portrait and landscape?
I've already tried everything with geometry render and frame (.infinity) but I can't get it.

someone who has managed to be able to have his ap in both modes with swuftui?

I attach my code and a couple of images.

[image]

```
 import SwiftUI

 struct OnBoardingView: View {


var ImageOnTop:some View{
    Image("headerPicture")
        .resizable()
        
}

var Title:some View {
    Text("Hey You")
        .font(.custom("Montserrat-Medium", size: 48))
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        
   
}
var subTitle:some View{
    Text("Out With A Porpuse ")
        .font(.custom("Montserrat-SemiBold", size: 16))
        .foregroundColor(.white)
}
var secondSubtitle:some View{
   
        Text("Find and build communities with people in your area. \n #GoodbyeCatfish \n #HellowConnections")
            .font(.custom("Montserrat-Regular", size: 16))
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)

}

var navigatinButton:some View{
    VStack(alignment:.center){
        
      NavigationLink(
        destination: CreateAccountView(),
        label: {
            Text("Create Account")
        })
    

        .font(.custom("Montserrat-Medium", size: 18))
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .frame(width: 230, height: 42, alignment: .center)
        .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 18)
                    .stroke(Color.yellow, lineWidth: 1.8))
        HStack{
            Text("Already have an account?")
                .font(.custom("Montserrat-Regular", size: 12))
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
            NavigationLink(
                destination: LoginView(LoginViewM: LoginViewModel()),
              label: {
                  Text("Log In")
              })
            
            .font(.custom("Montserrat-Regular", size: 12))
            .foregroundColor(.yellow)
        }
      

    }
}

var lastString: some View{
    HStack{
        Text("By using this app you agree with the")
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .font(.custom("Montserrat-Medium", size: 11))
            Text("terms of services")
            .underline(true, color: .yellow)
                .foregroundColor(.yellow)
                .font(.custom("Montserrat-Medium", size: 11))

    }
    .padding(30)
}



var body: some View {
    GeometryReader{ geometry in
        NavigationView{
        VStack(spacing:40){
            
            VStack(alignment: .center,spacing:15){
                ImageOnTop
                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: 270)
                Title
                subTitle
        }
            .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: 270)

        
          secondSubtitle
            .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: 75, alignment: .center)
            .padding(30)
            
        navigatinButton
           
            Spacer(minLength: 14)
           lastString
            Spacer().frame(height:20)
                        
        }
        
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        .background(Color.black)
    }
        .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height)
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
    }
    
}



 }

 struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
    OnBoardingView()
        .previewDevice(PreviewDevice(rawValue: "iPhone 12"))
        .previewDisplayName("iPhone 12")
        
    }
 }
```

Comment: SwiftUI does the auto layout for you that is one of its features. Adjusting for light and dark mode is another feature. The more parameters you hard code the more you have to compensate. If you use `GeometryReader` it is best to work in percentages vs hardcoding. It is very different than working with UIKit.

Comment: It's not entirely clear from you question what the desired output is. But, I notice a few things: 1) You don't need the `GeometryReader` -- everything can be done with `.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)` that you seem to need to do. 2) Use `+` to concatenate your `Text` elements instead of an `HStack` 3) Because of the heights of all of your elements, you will almost certainly need a `ScrollView` in landscape mode.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, I am trying to redraw my views in landscape to make it look great as in portrait, I just want to do auto layout like in UIKit but I don't know how to do it in swiftUI.

I'm trying to find out if someone already makes their app look good in device orientations.

Comment: Auto layout doesn’t exist for SwiftUI. SwiftUI does the work for you. Remove all your limitations. Especially the VStack spacings , the large paddings and the fixed frame sizes. Then work with %s for height using your geometry reader and set your buttons ideal sizes and maximum sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a version of your code that works for all screen sizes and positions. Less is more in SwiftUI. The more the hardcoded values the harder it is for SwiftUI to do the adjusting.

```
struct OnBoardingView: View {
    var ImageOnTop:some View{
        //Just to simulate,I switched to a system image you will have to adjust for your own
        Image(systemName: "square")
            .resizable()
            .foregroundColor(.blue)
    }
    
    var Title:some View {
        Text("Hey You")
            .font(.custom("Montserrat-Medium", size: 48))
            .foregroundColor(.white)
        
        
    }
    var subTitle:some View{
        Text("Out With A Porpuse ")
            .font(.custom("Montserrat-SemiBold", size: 16))
            .foregroundColor(.white)
    }
    var secondSubtitle:some View{
        VStack{
            Text("Find and build communities with people in your area.")
                .lineLimit(1)
            Text("#GoodbyeCatfish \n #HellowConnections")
        }
        
        .font(.custom("Montserrat-Regular", size: 16))
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
        .minimumScaleFactor(0.5)
    }
    
    var navigatinButton:some View{
        VStack(alignment:.center){
            NavigationLink(
                destination: Text("CreateAccountView()"),
                label: {
                    Text("Create Account")
                })
                .font(.custom("Montserrat-Medium", size: 18))
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                //Don't fix the size or thre won't be any differences between devices
                .frame(minWidth: 0, idealWidth: 230, maxWidth: 230, minHeight: 0, idealHeight: 42, maxHeight: 42, alignment: .center)
                .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 18)
                .stroke(Color.yellow, lineWidth: 1.8))
            HStack{
                Text("Already have an account?")
                    .font(.custom("Montserrat-Regular", size: 12))
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: Text("LoginView(LoginViewM: LoginViewModel()"),
                    label: {
                        Text("Log In")
                    })
                    .font(.custom("Montserrat-Regular", size: 12))
                    .foregroundColor(.yellow)
            }
        }
    }
    
    var lastString: some View{
        HStack{
            Text("By using this app you agree with the")
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .font(.custom("Montserrat-Medium", size: 11))
            Text("terms of services")
                .underline(true, color: .yellow)
                .foregroundColor(.yellow)
                .font(.custom("Montserrat-Medium", size: 11))
            
        }
        .padding(30)
    }
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader{ geometry in
            NavigationView{
                VStack{
                    ImageOnTop
                        .frame(height: geometry.size.height * 0.2)
                    VStack{
                        Title
                        subTitle
                    }.frame(height: geometry.size.height * 0.25)

                    Spacer()
                    secondSubtitle
                    //You can give spaces more weight by addign spacers
                    //This makes the space above the button twice as wide as the bottom
                    Spacer()
                    Spacer()
                    navigatinButton
                    Spacer()
                    lastString
                }
                .background(Color.black)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                .navigationBarHidden(true)
            }
            .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
        }
        
    }
}
```

[image: Portrait]

[image: Landscape]