# Responsive design swiftUI

Tags: swiftui

How can I make sure that my UI looks good on different devices such as the iPhone 13 and the iPhone 8?

Here is my code that is unresponsive

It is just a simple layout

```
import SwiftUI

let grey = Color(red: 0.928, green: 0.928, blue: 0.928)
let i = 0

var columns: [GridItem] =
Array(repeating: .init(.flexible()), count: 3)

let categories: [Category] = [
    .init(name: "Pasta", imageName: "square.and.arrow.up"),
    .init(name: "Asian", imageName: "square.and.arrow.down.fill"),
    .init(name: "Main", imageName: "rectangle.portrait.and.arrow.right"),
    .init(name: "Quick", imageName: "pencil.slash"),
    .init(name: "Veg", imageName: "scribble.variable"),
    .init(name: "Dessert", imageName: "pencil.circle.fill"),
]

struct SearchView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("Search For Recipes")
                .font(.system(size: 35))
                .padding(.top, 80)
                .padding(.horizontal, -70)
                .frame(width: 200, height: 10, alignment: .leading)
            Spacer()
            SearchBox()
                .padding(.top, 50)
            Spacer()
            Recomend()
                .padding(.top)
                .padding(.leading, -100)
            Spacer()
            LazyVGrid(columns: columns){
                ForEach((0...5), id: \.self) { _ in
                    MenuChoice()
                }
            }
            .padding(20)
            .padding(.bottom, 100)
            .padding(.top)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .frame(height:500)
        
            
        }
        
    }
}

struct SearchBox: View {
    var body: some View{
        VStack{
            HStack{
                Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
                Text("Search for recipes")
                
            }
            .frame(width: 200, height: 10, alignment: .leading)
            .padding(.trailing, 60)
        }
        .frame(width: 300, height: 50)
        .background(grey)
        .cornerRadius(8)
        .padding(.trailing, 50)
        
        
        
    }
}

struct MenuChoice: View{
    var body: some View{
        ZStack{
            ForEach(categories, id: \.self) { category in
                VStack{
                    Spacer()
                        .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                        .background(Color(red: 50, green: 207, blue: 255))
                        .cornerRadius(5)
                        .shadow(color: .init(.sRGB, white: 0.7, opacity: 1), radius: 4, x: 0.0, y: 2)
                        .padding(.bottom)
                        .overlay(
                            VStack(spacing: 8) {
                                Image(systemName: category.imageName)
                                    .padding(.top, -10)
                                    .font(.system(size: 30))
                                Text(category.name)
                                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                                    .font(.system(size: 20))
                                    .padding(.top, 5)
                                
                            }
                        )
                }
                
            }
            
        }
    }
}

struct Recomend: View{
    var body: some View{
        Button {
            print("Image tapped!")
        } label: {
            ZStack{
                
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
                    .frame(width: 250, height: 50)
                    .foregroundColor(grey)

                Text("See All Recomended Recipes")
                    .foregroundColor(Color.black)
            }

            
        }
    }
}

struct SearchView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SearchView()
            .previewDevice(PreviewDevice(rawValue: "iPhone 13"))
        SearchView()
            .previewDevice(PreviewDevice(rawValue: "iPhone 8"))
    }
}
```

On the iPhone 13 it looks good but on the iPhone 8 it looks squashed and not good.
How can i make my code responsive for different screen heights/widths?

Comment: Don't use hardcode in layout: frames, paddings, etc. then everything will layout depending on content and free space.

Comment: @Asperi what should i be using then?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67187484/autolayout-in-swiftui/67195092#67195092

Answer (score 0):

Following the comments you could go in this direction:
This adapts nicely and also is a lot less code.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("Search For Recipes")
                .font(.system(size: 35))
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
            SearchBox()
                .padding(.bottom)
                .padding(.bottom)
            Recomend()
            Spacer()
            LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 18){
                ForEach(categories) { category in
                    MenuChoice(category: category)
                }
            }
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding()
        
    }
}

struct SearchBox: View {
    var body: some View{
        VStack {
            HStack{
                Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
                Text("Search for recipes")
            }
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
        .padding()
        .background(grey)
        .cornerRadius(8)
    }
}

struct MenuChoice: View{
    let category: Category
    var body: some View{
        VStack(spacing: 8) {
            Image(systemName: category.imageName)
                .padding(.top)
                .font(.system(size: 30))
            Text(category.name)
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                .font(.system(size: 20))
                .padding(.bottom)
        }
        .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
        .background(Color(red: 50, green: 207, blue: 255))
        .cornerRadius(5)
        .shadow(color: .init(.sRGB, white: 0.7, opacity: 1), radius: 4, x: 0.0, y: 2)
    }
}


struct Recomend: View{
    var body: some View{
        Button {
            print("Image tapped!")
        } label: {
                Text("See All Recomended Recipes")
                .padding()
                    .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                    .background(grey)
                    .cornerRadius(8)
        }
   }
}
```