# Content isn't horizontally aligned - Swift UI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am new to Swift UI, and am working on my first app on XCode. I just finished creating my app, and when I tried it with different versions and screen sizes everything was out of line horizontally. In some cases, it was just not in the center and others it was off of the screen. I thought Swift UI was supposed to align everything automatically, and so I think I might have messed something up in a VStack.

I tried adding an wrapping the main VStack inside an HStack with an alignment guide of .center. I expected it to align the VStack (which all the content is in) to the center horizontally. It ended up changing nothing.

Comment: Can you possibly edit your question to include an example of the code that’s causing you layout problems? It’s tricky to diagnose such situations with no code to go on. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Autolayout in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67187484/autolayout-in-swiftui)