# SwiftUI how to make UI Responsiv

Tags: swift, xcode, design-patterns, swiftui, responsive-design

[UI on iPhone Pro Max here the UI is not in the right place](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBxlq.png)

[UI on iPhone Pro thats perfectly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yj8QD.png)

Hello I am new to SwiftUI and have a question. I had to implement the UI with the Star and the Number Count. I did everything, but when I switch the phones my UI is miss placed depends on the iPhone I choose. How can I fix that ? I search in the Internet for Responsiveness in SwiftUI but it didn't really helped me. I thought also that SwiftUI does most of the Responsiveness because I know in UIKIT you have to declare the constraints by yourself. Thanks for helping me, the Code is below. I also have after the CustomerCardPoints an List which works perfectly but since I added the CustomerCardPoints there is a small space between the Views, if anybody has experience how can I fix that also? (Not Necessary)

```
var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
             
                shopModel.logo
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .frame(maxWidth: 200, maxHeight: 100)
                    .padding([.top, .leading, .trailing])
                
                Text(shopModel.name)
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .padding()
                
            CustomerCardPoints()
            
            }


struct CustomerCardPoints: View {
    var body: some View {
            VStack(){
                ZStack() {
                    Image("Slice")
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        .frame(maxWidth: 180, maxHeight: 60)
                        .offset(x: 160, y: -127)
                    HStack(alignment: .firstTextBaseline) {
                        Text("22")
                            .font(.system(size: 19))
                            .fontWeight(.bold)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .offset(x: 237, y: -126)
                        Image("favoriten")
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                            .frame(width: 110, height: 25)
                            .offset(x: 132, y: -120)
                        
                    }
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: All of those hardcoded values should be removed. Use percentages, alignments and spaces with SwiftUI less constraints is better.

Comment: Do you have an Example by any chance, I coded that what I found about SwiftUI in the net

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67187484/autolayout-in-swiftui/67195092#67195092) is another question I worked out for someone. Try the [Apple SwiftUI Tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui) Any tutorial for SwiftUI that has you inputting all those constraints is made by someone that doesn’t know SwiftUI so don’t use them as a sample. Less is best.