# SwiftUI Interface Design

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am building an app that is made for ipad only and I was designing the interface on an ipad pro 12.9 inch 6th gen and then I ran it on an ipad 10th gen and the interface was all out of place and I dont know how to add constriants in swiftUI.
here is some code for the interface.

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct GroupPrintLabelPopup: View {
    @State private var value = 0
       let step = 1
       let range = 1...50

    var body: some View {
        ZStack  {
            popUpBackGround()
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 1, leading: 300, bottom: 0, trailing: 300))
                .foregroundStyle(Color("Color 1"))
               
            
            VStack(spacing:15) {
                Text("Close")
                    .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 20, leading: 650, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
                    .foregroundStyle(.white)
                    .font(.title2)
               Text("Group Print Labels")
                    .foregroundStyle(.white)
                    .font(.title)
                    .padding(.top,-42)
                ZStack(alignment: .top) {
                    Rectangle()
                        .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 1, leading: 300, bottom: 1, trailing: 300))
                        .foregroundStyle(Color("Color"))
                    VStack(spacing: 50){
                        Text("Select Label Format")
                    } .padding(.top).padding(.trailing,580)
                        
                    VStack {
                        Text("Select Label Quantity")
                    }.padding(.top)
                    VStack(spacing:150) {
                            Button {
                                
                            } label: {
                                GroupPrintLabelBtn(text: "Print Selected labels", textColor: .white, backgroundColor: Color("Color 2"))
                            }
                        Button {
                            
                        } label: {
                          Text("Select All")
                                .font(.title)
                                .padding(.leading,120)
                        }
                    }.padding(.leading,480).padding(.top,35)
                    List(0..<20) { list in
                        CatalogRow()
                    }
                    .navigationTitle("Square Catalog")
                    .listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle()).padding(EdgeInsets(top: 350, leading: 300, bottom: 10, trailing: 300))
                }
            }
        }
    }
        
}



#Preview {
   GroupPrintLabelPopup()
}
```

Comment: Don’t use hardcoded values, it is better to use percentages based on GeometryReader or even better use SwiftUI.Layout. The more you define the more you have to compensate. SwiftUI was made to adapt, use the natural behaviors. Forget about “constraints” use alignments, spacers, percentages. If you have to use a # use ScaledMetric too.

Comment: Can you show me an example of how it would look using alignments, spacers, percentages?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67187484/autolayout-in-swiftui/67195092#67195092

Comment: Ok thank you for your help.

Comment: Also as a personal preference I always use the smallest device for quick prototyping and changes when working on my UI it is much easier to scale up than it is to scale down UI.

Comment: Ok, I will give it a try.

Comment: Specific numbers are acceptable as stylistic preferences (e.g. padding or spacing), and limits (minimal/maximal values). They are absolutely a horrible and unmanageable method of placing the elements on the screen. Things like `EdgeInsets(top: 1, leading: 300, bottom: 1, trailing: 300)` should not exist in any app.

Comment: In most cases you should rely on auto-layout (i.e. place your elements with relation to each other, and let them grow / shrink, based on screen size. For example the text inside Vstack (`VStack(spacing:15) {Text("Close")`) has no excuse to ever have `EdgeInsets(leading: 650)` - that's just wrong usage of the features provided by SwiftUI. And there's always a way to express something like this better. Also use elements for what they are designed: `Close` sounds like an action button, so use `Button` instead of `Text`.

Comment: In very rare cases you will need to use GeometryReader, but looking at your UI, I don't see any need for that - it''s a very simple UI. Just learn how to do auto-layout properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Spacer and alignment guides for positioning instead of hardcoded padding values.

```
struct GroupPrintLabelPopup: View {
    @State private var value = 0
    let step = 1
    let range = 1...50

    var body: some View {
        ZStack  {
            popUpBackGround()
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                .padding()
                .foregroundStyle(Color("Color 1"))
            
            VStack(spacing:15) {
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Text("Close")
                        .foregroundStyle(.white)
                        .font(.title2)
                        .padding([.top, .trailing])
                }
                Text("Group Print Labels")
                    .foregroundStyle(.white)
                    .font(.title)
                
                ZStack(alignment: .top) {
                    Rectangle()
                        .padding()
                        .foregroundStyle(Color("Color"))
                    
                    VStack(spacing: 50){
                        Text("Select Label Format")
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                            .padding([.leading])
                        
                        Text("Select Label Quantity")
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                            .padding([.leading])
                        
                        VStack(spacing:150) {
                            Button(action: {}) {
                                GroupPrintLabelBtn(text: "Print Selected labels", textColor: .white, backgroundColor: Color("Color 2"))
                            }
                            Button(action: {}) {
                                Text("Select All")
                                    .font(.title)
                            }
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .trailing)
                            .padding([.trailing])
                        }
                        .padding()
                        
                        List(0..<20) { list in
                            CatalogRow()
                        }
                        .listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())
                        .padding()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```