# Place Title and Button at Top and Bottom of Screen in Both Landscape and Portrait Orientation in Swift UI

Tags: swift, swiftui, vstack

I am trying to make the jump from Objective-C's graphical UI to coding the UI in Swift.

I have a View that looks okay in portrait mode, but when the device is rotated, the title and buttons move off screen.

[image]

```
 var body: some View {
    ZStack(content: {
        Image("XCTrack")
            .padding(20.0)
            .scaledToFit()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            .padding()
            .opacity(0.8)
  
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 20.0, content: {
                Spacer()
                .frame(height:  screenHeight/6)
            
                Text("Instrument Tuner")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.red)

            Spacer()
                .frame(height:2 * screenHeight/3)
            
                Button("Start Tuning") {
                         DoSomeTuning
                }
                
                .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
                .tint(.red)
                .font(.largeTitle
                )
                .alignmentGuide(HorizontalAlignment.center, 
                 computeValue: { dimension in screenWidth
                })
            Spacer()
                .frame(height: screenHeight/6)
            
        })  
    })
}
```

The calculated values for the frames were designed to place the title and button close to the upper and lower bounderies of screen, respectively. If there is a better way to accomplish this, I am willing to jettison this method.

As an aside, it seems that .alignmentGuide(HorizontalAlignment.center should center the button on screen, but it is not doing this.

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Comment: Don’t hardcode values, the more you hardcode the more you have to compensate SwiftUI does most of the work for you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67187484/autolayout-in-swiftui/67195092#67195092

Comment: @loremipsum, that works! If you want to put your comment as a response, I will check it off as the answer! Thanks.