SwiftUI layout doesn't look the same on all devices
I have installed my test code on two of my phones. I have an iPhone XS Max and an iPhone 11. The app looks different on each phone and I am not sure how to fix it so it looks the same.
I have attached two images the first one is on the iPhone XS Max and that is how I want it to look on all devices. The second is on the iPhone 11.
I will attach my code here.
import SwiftUI
import AVFoundation

// Model
class PostItem: ObservableObject, Identifiable {
    @Published var item: String = ""
}

// ViewModel
class ProfileViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var offerImages: [UIImage] = [UIImage(named: "AppIcon")!, UIImage(named: "AppIcon")!, UIImage(named: "AppIcon")!]
    @Published var posts: [PostItem] = []
    @Published var profession: String = "Profession"
    @Published var bio: String = "Bio"
    @Published var bi: String = "BI"
    @Published var bioText: String = "Bio text"
    @Published var proText: String = "Pro text"
    @Published var biText: String = "BI text"
    @Published var currentImageIndex: Int = 0
    
    private var player: AVAudioPlayer!
    private var timer: Timer?
    
    init() {
        for _ in 0..<6 {
            let newItem = PostItem()
            newItem.item = "This is a test post to see the character limit"
            posts.append(newItem)
        }
        startTimer()
    }
    
    func startTimer() {
        timer?.invalidate()
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 5.0, repeats: true) { [weak self] _ in
            self?.slideToNext()
        }
    }
    
    private func slideToNext() {
        withAnimation {
            currentImageIndex = (currentImageIndex + 1) % offerImages.count
        }
    }
    
    private func playSound() {
        guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "TEST MUSIC", withExtension: "mp3") else { return }
        player = try? AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
        player.numberOfLoops = -1 // Loop indefinitely
        player.play()
    }
}

// Custom Button Style
struct PrimaryButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .scaleEffect(configuration.isPressed ? 0.95 : 1.0)
            .padding()
            .frame(width: 100, height: 50)
            .background(
                Image("gradient 1")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFill()
            )
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .cornerRadius(8)
            .offset(x: 0, y: -100)
    }
}

// Custom Collection View
struct CollectionView: View {
    var images: [UIImage]
    @Binding var currentIndex: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ZStack {
                ForEach(0..<images.count, id: \.self) { index in
                    if index == currentIndex {
                        Image(uiImage: images[index])
                            .resizable()
                            .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height)
                            .transition(.opacity)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}



// Main View
struct ProfileScreenView: View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = ProfileViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            CollectionView(images: viewModel.offerImages, currentIndex: $viewModel.currentImageIndex)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            
            ScrollView {
                VStack {
                    Image(uiImage: UIImage(named: "blank_profile")!)
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .frame(width: 99, height: 99)
                        .clipShape(Circle())
                        .padding()
                    
                    HStack {
                        Button("Connect") {
                            // Handle connect action
                        }
                        .buttonStyle(PrimaryButtonStyle())
                        
                        Spacer()
                        
                        Button("Tap In") {
                            // Handle tap in action
                        }
                        .buttonStyle(PrimaryButtonStyle())
                    }
                    .padding()
                    
                    List(viewModel.posts) { post in
                        Text(post.item)
                            .background(Color.purple)
                    }
                    .background(Color.blue)
                    .frame(height: 300)
                    
                    ProfileDetailsView()
                        .offset(x: 48, y: -390)
                }
                .padding()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ProfileScreenView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ProfileScreenView()
    }
}

I have tried using the display width and height to scale the elements I also used GeometryReader to scale thing. I expected that to fix everything although it just cut off part of the app on the iPhone 11.



It isn't clear exactly what your issue is. Is it the background image?  With SwiftUI it is generally a mistake to try and use absolute positioning. Different devices have different resolutions and even different pixel densities. Things will look different in different devices. You should design your views around the desired layout, not pixel perfect locations.

If you're attempting to scale content size up or down depending on the device, you're going to break accessibility badly. If the user has asked for larger fonts (or smaller ones), you should honor that need, and expect that you as a developer will not have control over precision sizing.

Don’t hardcode values https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67187484/autolayout-in-swiftui/67195092#67195092

I am wondering why this code does not look the same on all devices I thought that it would look the same because I used the devices width and height to scale the elements. link

They can't ever look "exactly the same" because the two devices have slightly different screen sizes. By using a GeometryReader and trying to force absolute sizes for certain elements, you are fighting the framework. That's not the way we do things in SwiftUI.
I see that your screenshots are the same dimension. I think it would be easier for you to see what's happening if you use "Physical Size" (command-1) on the Simulator for both devices. For good measure, throw in an iPhone 15 Pro Max (also in "Physical Size" mode).
Do you expect all 3 displays to be scaled versions of each other? Or should one be in letterbox mode? Or should one be clipped? What behavior do you want to see when the device is in landscape mode? What do you expect when the user makes the font larger (or smaller) ("Increase Font Size" on the Simulator, option-command-plus)? What should it look like when I run the app on an iPad?
